# Using custom filters generated from KMeans as the first set of filters in Keras CNN

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I've generated a bunch of filters from some images using KMeans and I want to initialise the filters of a Keras Convolutional Neural Network. Is that possible and how would I implement that? Would I need to change the source code for my needs or can I use layers.core.Lambda to implement that?

Comment: you should be able to stack the features and pass as a numpy array? Is it not working that way?

Comment: Is this through the weights parameter that I should initialise when I create a convolution2d?

Comment: you might be using something like `inputs = Input((3, cols, rows))` in keras. Here 3 is the for regular RGB images. You can set it to a different number based on what your input data is.

Comment: Thank you very much Krishna! So basically I have 25 filters 2d filters and I want to initialise the convolutional neural network with those filters - how would that be possible through Keras

Comment: Also are cols and rows therefore the initial filter weights or are they the activation maps? Can I do something similar by setting the weights in the covolution2d layer?

Comment: If you want to set the filters as weights, what would be the input to your network?

Comment: I might have understood you wrong. As per my initial understanding, the 25 filters are obtained from the input using some kind of feature extraction method. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Krishna that is correct - the filters are generated from the input through feature extraction and I want to use those filters as initial filters for subsequent training. The input to the network would still be images or would that be incorrect?

Comment: I am not sure if you can use those filters as initial weights to train on input images. Even if you try to use, I think you cannot have multiple convolution layers in your network. However, it is possible to use those filters and build a fully-connected network on top to inference.

Comment: No but I would just use the filters as initial weights in the convolution2d weight parameter? These weights can then undergo training to be changed. Would that work?

Comment: I am not aware of a method to do that. May be you need to tweak the Keras source a little.

Comment: I will try putting the filters into the weights parameter in convolution2d at https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/. Thanks! Just out of curiosity when you say stack filters on top of fully connected how would I do that?

Comment: I meant to use a flatten layer on top of filters and use a fully connected layers over that.

Comment: Yes... setting the weights parameter in convolution2d layers might work. Best of luck!